# Http services in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

Does http post service contribute in creating a todo list. I need to save the list of tasks as a file in computer whenever the user hits the enter.

Comment: Wow! That's great. Where is the code? What's the error?

Comment: Read this: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Comment: I don't have the code right now. But i just googled about http post. What they gave me was very much complicated

Answer (score 1):

Here is some code sample how you can use post data in angulajs

```
$http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: <ServiceUrl>, // this is url of service in backend
        data: {firstname:"xyz",lastname:"abc"}, // data to be posted
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' } // format of data
    })
    .success(function (response) {
        // performs some operation on success
    })
    .error(function (response) {
        // performs some operation on failure
    });
```

Comment: What role the headers part play??

Comment: In above case header is telling your service that you are passing data in JSON format.

Comment: Thanks.. i appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

If you want to post some data from your client code to server, you can use angularjs post service. You can test your post service using chrome postman extension or some other similar tool.

Comment: What answer is this?

Comment: Answer to "Where and when to use it?", question seems too generic,  instead of marking it negative its better to provide the requester some basics..

Comment: I need a simplified example of using http post service.